# Upgrading Application using InstallShield

Tags: c#, python, installshield, patch, software-distribution

This is the situation I have:

I created an installer. It has python scripts, executable, and other file types. In the installer, I run a C# executable as a custom action, after registering the product. The C# executable moves the files into different locations (i.e. a text document will be moved to My Documents). I understand I can do this without the custom actions, but I was not aware of that when I created the installer.

Now, after I have distributed the software, users are running into small bugs. For instance, there is a bad if check in one of the python scripts.

***Question*** Is there a way to fix the portion of the python script/executable/text document that is broken, and simply update those files (without having to redistribute the software to the users, and having them reinstall it)?

Answer (score 0):

A patch probably won't help you. If the locations are fixed within the install, a minor upgrade could do the trick, if you make all the files that need to stay the same "never overwrite" (unless the custom action ignores this, then things might get difficult).

If the locations are determined during the execution of the custom action, or the locations are based on user input during the install, then you have a problem if you haven't saved the location paths (in the registry, for example). I don't think you want a custom action to scan all the drives of the computer just to find the files.

If the files are put in their new locations by the custom action, windows installer probably won't see them as key files and probably won't "repair" them in any scenario. If the fixes are few, you might be better of distributing the files separately with a clear instruction, in stead of spending many hours on a difficult new custom action.

Cheers, B.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The file that needs to be overwritten is in the exe file in the Program Files directory for the application (for this instance). Would the minor upgrade be the route to go for this time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, apparently I missed the trigger that you had placed a comment.

If this is this something you would like to know, look at this table. It shows when to use major, minor or small fix (patch).

Hope it helps.

Cheers!

http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/MajorMinorSmall.htm